# Accessing Big Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I've been doing some profiling on different methods of accessing large(ish) arrays of data in PHP.  The use case is pretty simple: some of our tools output data into PHP files as associative arrays and these files are considered static data by the application.  We make games, so some examples of data files would include items in a catalog, tasks that a user must complete, or definitions for maps:

```
<?php
$some_data = array(
    ...lots and lots of stuff in here...
);
?>
```

Since these arrays are large-ish(400K), and much of our code is interested in this data, it becomes necessary to access this data as efficiently as possible.  I settled on timing 3 different patterns for doing this.  After presenting the methods I will share my results below.

What I'm looking for is some experience based validation on these methods and their timing as well as any other methods to try out.

### Method #1: getter function

In the method, the exporter actually creates a file that looks like:

```
<?php
function getSomeData()
{
    $some_data = array(
        ...lots and lots of stuff here...
    );
    return $some_data;
}
?>
```

Client code can then get the data by simply calling getSomeData() when they want it.

### Method #2: global + include

In this method the data file looks identical to the original code block above, however the client code must jump through a few hoops to get the data into a local scope.  This assumes the array is in a file called 'some_data.php';

```
global $some_data; //must be the same name as the variable in the data file...
include 'some_data.php';
```

This will bring the $some_data array into scope, though it is a bit cumbersome for client code (my opinion).

### Method #3: getter by reference

This method is nearly identical to Method #1, however the getter function does not return a value but rather sets a reference to the data.

```
<?php
function getSomeDataByRef($some_data)
{
    $some_data = array(
        ...lots and lots of stuff here...
    );
    return $some_data;
}
?>
```

Client code then retrieves the data by declaring a local variable (called anything) and passing it by reference to the getter:

```
$some_data_anyname = array();
getSomeDataByRef(&$some_data_anyname);
```

### Results

So I ran a little script that runs each of these methods of retrieving data 1000 times on and averages the run time (computed by microtime(true) at the beginning and end).  The following are my results (in ms, running on a MacBookPro 2GHz, 8GB RAM, PHP version 5.3.4):

#### METHOD #1:

> AVG: 0.0031637034416199
>   MAX: 0.0043289661407471
>   MIN: 0.0025908946990967

#### METHOD #2:

> AVG: 0.01434082698822
>   MAX: 0.018275022506714
>   MIN: 0.012722969055176

#### METHOD #3:

> AVG: 0.00335768699646
>   MAX: 0.0043489933013916
>   MIN: 0.0029017925262451

It seems pretty clear, from this data anyway, that the global+include method is inferior to the other two, which are "negligible" difference.

Thoughts? 
Am I completely missing anything? (probably...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, very nice question for a first. I'm glad to see someone reads those FAQs. Second, I think it would be better for you to be using a data structure and objects. I.e, a `Task` class to describe tasks, `Level` to describe levels (and maybe hold `Task`  objects?), `Player` to describe players etc. Beats an associative array IMHO.

Comment: Could you explain why you're using PHP files as a data store? Why not store the data in a RDBMS (or equivalent) and access it from there? Perhaps I misunderstood but it seems like you're generating PHP files to store data?

Comment: Your referencing is the wrong way round. The `&` should be in the function declaration, call-time pass-by-reference is deprecated - i.e. it should be `function getSomeDataByRef(&$some_data)` and `getSomeDataByRef($some_data_anyname);`. Also note that pre-declaring the passed variable as an array in unnecessary. `include` will always be less efficient, due to the fact that it has to fire up the parser again. I suspect the reason the others are negligible difference is because the first version will still be implemented as copy-on-write, and does not require a memory copy for the return value.

Comment: Return the array instead of assigning it to `$some_data` and just use `$some_data = include('some_data')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what your looking for but it should help out with speed and memory issues. You can use the fixed spl array:

```
$startMemory = memory_get_usage();
$array = new SplFixedArray(100000);
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; ++$i) {
    $array[$i] = $i;
}
echo memory_get_usage() - $startMemory, ' bytes';
```

Read more on big php arrays here:
http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html

Also have you thought about storing the data in a cache/memory? For example you could use mysqlite with the inmemory engine on the first execution then access data from there:

```
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
// .. Use PDO as normal
```

Comment: We've made the decision to use associative arrays as opposed to objects for performance reasons.  I understand that those reasons may or may not be debunk with PHP5, but that decision is unlikely to change.  RDBMS is not used for similar performance reasons: establishing a connection and running a query is simply to slow for us in practice.

Comment: We do cache the data to some extent and I guess I wasn't clear about that...ie, we will only 'get' the data once for a given class/web service in it's constructor.  What I am interested in the fastest way to get that data into scope. Thanks.

Comment: While I normally tend to favour arrays for smaller things, like config, batch importing and such - you should wrap access to the data in some LazyArray- or StreamArray - object that never have more than a fixed chuck-size in memory at a time. If you implement an Iterator, you could still do global searches or have keyed access to the whole thing, just might have to iterate a few times first, or just implement like a [CallbackFilterIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.callbackfilteriterator.php)

Answer (score 3):

For one of my projects in which a database was not an option, I faced the same problem of loading big (by big I mean series of 3 MB files) php files containing arrays in memory and I was looking for options to maximize the performances. I found a very easy one which was caching these files on the disk as json at first use. I divided load time by 3 and also memory peak consumption by 30%. Loading local json file with json_decode() is much much faster than including a big php file containing an array. it also has the advantage of being a format that most languages can manipulate directly. Hope that helps.

Comment: Good solution. Also in my tests parsing the json file and getting it as array is around 10% faster than getting as object.