# How to avoid circular bot traps in phpcrawl?

Tags: php, web-crawler

How can I avoid getting trapped in circular link traps using when using PHP-crawl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the url's you've visited in some sort of array you could do a check to see if the url has already been visited and if so, don't visit it again.

Comment: So there is no built-in feature for this in phpcrawl? I assume just using arrays will quickly exhaust memory for large crawls, then again maybe I should move up to more heavy-duty software for crawling on a large scale...

Comment: RAM is cheap (generally speaking). That being said,  http://php.net/SplFixedArray might be of some use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434913/accessing-big-arrays-in-php has some more reading on this as well. If you're okay with longer crawl times you could even use the file system and put each domain in a file that contains a json array and load things up that way. It'll be slower but less memory intensive.